# Slick + JTDS + SQL Server failver partner?

Tags: sql-server, slick, jtds

Have a Scala application which connects to a SQL Server database via Slick, using the JTDS driver.  Works great.

However, I'd like to be able to specify a DB failover partner (alternative DB server, in case the primary falls over).  Have done this with Java apps running in app containers, by adding ";failoverPartner=ip.address.of.partner" to the JDBC URL for the DB connections.

JTDS doesn't seem to like this syntax.  (I infer this by 1) using the syntax in the JDBC URL in my applicztion.conf with a valid IP address for the failover, but 2) giving an unreachable address for the primary DB, and observing that I can't get a connection.)

Is there support in either JTDS or Slick for specifying a DB failover partner?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as jTDS is concerned, the DEV discussion at the link below specifically states that it doesn't support SQL Server failover.

http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/discussion/104388/thread/22079bd7/